# Modeling for alternate gambling in an exercise of Karlin and Pinsky's book

Tags: probability, gambling

The following is an exercise from Pinsky and Karlin's *An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling* (4th edition):

> [image]

---

I'm trying to do (b) by analyzing the possible sequence of playing. Given that $A$ wins, denote $N$ as the number of plays. Denote $A0$ as $A$ losses and $A1$ as $A$ wins. 
When $N$ is odd, the possible situations are
$$
A1;\\
A0B0A1;\\
A0B0A0B0A1;\\
\cdots
$$
and when $N$ is even,
$$
B0A1;\\
B0A0B0A1;\\
B0A0B0A0B0A1;\\
\cdots
$$

I think that  the distribution of $N$ is given by
$$
P(N=2k+1)=x^kp,\quad P(N=2k)=(1-q)x^{k-1}p
$$
where $x=(1-p)(1-q)$.

However, when I add these number up, I don't get the desired number $1$ unless $p=q=1/2$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^kp+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-q)x^{k-1}p\neq 1.
$$

Here are my **questions**:

- What is wrong with the reasoning? How would you write down the correct one?
- For the event in (a) be $(N\textrm{ is odd})$?

Comment: Check: If A plays first, when B plays is it the second play, or still the first?

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Sorry. I don't understand your comment..

Comment: It seems that you should say $P(N=2k)=x^{k-1}(1-p)q$, if you want to calculate the probability that $B$ wins

Comment: @Jack,  What is the definition of "a play"? Are you counting the times the machine is played, or the rounds $A$ and $B$ play against each other.  From your attempt it seems the former, and my answer uses that, but it should be made clear.

Comment: @Jack: I think in the problem it is given that $A$ plays first. So sequences like $B0A0B0A1$ should not be possible. Or do they flip a coin to determine who starts first? You need to be more clear.

Comment: @Momo: This is a very good point. In fact, if one does not the probability of who plays first, I think (b) cannot be answered unless (b) is under the situation that A plays first. Now things become clearer for me and I will write up my thoughts later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inaccuracy is $P(N=2k-1)=x^{k-1}p$ and $P(N=2k)=x^{k-1}(1-p)q$

So in order for $B$ to win in the $2k$th play, nobody should win in the first $2k-2$ plays, then $A$ should lose and $B$ should win.

Now it sums to $1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}p+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}(1-p)q=\frac{p}{1-x}+\frac{(1-p)q}{1-x}=\frac{1-x}{1-x}=1$$

Your last sentence is correct:

$$P(A\text{ wins})=P(N\text{ odd})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}p=\frac{p}{1-x}$$

Finally for part b):

$$E[N|A\text{ wins}]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k-1)P(A\text{ wins in }2k-1\text{ plays}|A\text{ wins})\\
=\frac{1}{P(A\text{ wins})}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k-1)P(A\text{ wins in }2k-1\text{ plays})\\
=\frac{1-x}{p}p\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k-1)x^{k-1}=(1-x)\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand the second line: what is "in order for $B$ to win" from? Would you please elaborate? Are you addressing (b) or (a)?

Comment: For example when $k=3$, the sequence is $A0B0A0B0A0B1$. so both $A$ and $B$ should lose twice, then $A$ should lose and finally $B$ should win.

Comment: According to your comment under the question, do you mean $E(N|\textrm{A wins and A plays first})$ in your answer of part (b)? Likewise, all the probability $P$ in the calculation is $P(\cdot\mid\textrm{A plays first})$.

Comment: Yes, $A$ plays first is assumed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited thanks to MOMO's comment]

---

Bad notations (which appear in OP) would cause lots of confusion. I would try to be careful with the writing.

(a) What one wants to calculate is the conditional probability
$$
P(\textrm{A wins}\mid \textrm{A plays first}). 
$$
Instead of working with the formula in the definition of conditional probability
$$
P(C\mid D)=\frac{P(C\wedge D)}{P(D)},
$$
we work with the probability measure $P(\cdot\mid  \textrm{A plays first})$ instead. The "conditional event" that "A wins" is the disjoint union of the following events:

A1;
A0B0A1;
A0B0A0B0A1;
...

the probability of which can thus be calculated as
$$
\begin{align}
&P(\textrm{A wins}\mid \textrm{A plays first})\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(N=2k+1\mid\textrm{A plays first})\\
=&p(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=\frac{p}{1-x}
\end{align}
$$
where $x=(1-p)(1-q)$ and $N$ denotes the number of plays. Note that we explicitly assume that the event that "A (B) wins in a single play" is independent of the event "A plays first".

(b) This problem is ambiguous. It could possibly mean the following two cases:

- $E(N\mid\textrm{A wins})$
- $E(N\mid\textrm{A wins and A plays first})$

In the first case, without knowing the probability of who plays first, one does not have enough information to answer it. Suppose we are doing the second one. Then one should work on the *conditional* distribution of $N$, namely, find $P(N=k\mid\textrm{A wins and A plays first})$. Denote the event that A wins as $A_W$ and the event that A plays first as $A_F$.

Now we should work on the probability measure $P(\cdot\mid A_WA_F)$ instead of $P$. <s>In the smaller world "given A wins and A plays first", "B loses a single play" is a **sure** event. (Note that "A wins" here means "A wins the game", not a single play.)</s>
On the other hand,
$$
P(N=2k+1\mid A_WA_F)=\frac{P(N=2k+1, A_W\mid A_F)}{P(A_W\mid A_F)}
$$ 
where the denominator is given by (a) and the numerator
$$
P(N=2k+1, A_W\mid A_F)=x^{k}p.
$$

Note in particular that $P(N=2k+1\mid A_WA_F)=0$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Now the conditional expectation is given by
$$
E(N\mid A_WA_F)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2k+1)P(N=2k+1\mid A_WA_F)
$$

---

The original wrong answer is as follows
$$
E(N\mid A_WA_F)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2k-1)(1-p)^kp.
$$
An easy counter example is that when $q=p=1$, one should have $E(E\mid A_WA_F)=1$, but the result above gives $0$.

Comment: Your $E[N|A_wA_F]$ does not depend on $q$. But think about the case when $q=1$. Then $E[N|A_wA_F]=1$ (if $A$ does not win from the first try, doesn't get another chance). This is not captured in the formula.